# ios12/13: Страница отображена WKWebView в мусорной кодировке

Tags: ios, webkit

Можно как то поправить это

```
ÐšÐ¾Ð¿Ð¸Ñ Ñ‡ÐµÐºÐ°
ÐžÐÐž "Ð‘Ð°Ð½Ðº Ð‘ÐµÐ»Ð’Ð­Ð‘"
ÐšÐ°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ‡ÐºÐ°: 5.9830 Mastercard World EUR
RRN: 932601237619
ÐšÐ¾Ð´ Ð°Ð²Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð·.: 681633
Ð”Ð°Ñ‚Ð°: 22.11.2019 20:01:47
Ð¡ÑƒÐ¼Ð¼Ð°: 7,00 BYN

ÐžÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð° Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð² Ð¸ ÑƒÑÐ»ÑƒÐ³ BCARD 419-a0a3-4194-9c04-192caf67d1cf
```

на клиенте или надо сказать верстальщтикам чтобы они это побороли у себя?

Comment: Можно поправить, а можно и сказать верстальщикам.

Comment: а каким образорм поправить?

Comment: Не, пардон. Я думал это в браузере, там можно кодировку поменять. А это вебвью. Тогда надо верстальщиков пинать, чтобы правильно кодировку указали.

Comment: ок, поправил титул